# Checking the correlation/mutual information between the model's output and the labels

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics

I'm training some net with a supervised learning setting. The inputs are vectors and the outputs (and labels) are numbers.

I am using MSE loss and the loss reduces with time (on both train and test set), but I am still not sure whether the net actually learns to predict a label from the input or does it simply learn to output numbers that resemble the labels distribution better.

If I would take labels vector and outputs vector for each epoch and check the correlation/mutual information between them could it give me a sense of whether the nets actually improves? 
I am not familiar with such work, Is it common to do something of the sort?

Comment: You mention that the target is a quantity. If the quantity is actually noninteger and you only have integer values available, then MSE is defensible as the loss function, although it seems possible that there could be another that's even better. But if the quantities are actually integers, I don't think MSE is appropriate, since it originates from an assumption of Gaussian noise. What do the data represent? The loss function should be derived from that. Since this is a conceptual question, I think you'll get more and better responses on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendations. 
Without redundant elaboration, the labels are the number of times the x object appears somewhere, so the labels are non-negative integers from 0 to around 20 I would say (possibly larger than 20, though). 
Is there another loss function you would recommend?

Comment: OK, the target is actually only an integer, so the distribution of the target given the inputs has to be some discrete distribution. You mention it's the number of times an object appears -- my first guess is that a reasonable first guess is that it's a Poisson distribution. The output of your model is probably going to be the parameter lambda, which is also the expected value. I don't know immediately what the negative log-likelihood, i.e. your loss function, is going to be, although it might be some entropy-like quantity such as x log(x) where x is the target.

Comment: I think a web search for "Poisson regression" should turn up some resources. If you have not already done so, you should seriously consider bringing up this question on stats.stackexchange.com. I would be interested to see what people say there.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443537/checking-the-correlation-mutual-information-between-the-models-output-and-the-l

Answer (score 0):

If your labels are classes/descrete (i.e. 0, 1, 2 ...), you should consider using another loss (multicategorical cross_entropy), from which you could easely output metrics as accuracy, perplexity, etc.

However, you could still think of it as a regression problem (as you do, if I understand it well), i.e continuous predictions and discrete labels, and output accuracy for example using round(predictions).

Comment: My labels are not classes, they are number that says something about the object.

Comment: Are they discrete or continuous ?

Comment: They are discrete and non negative (they represent an amount)

Comment: Ok, so why not thinking of these labels as classes, and use multicategorical cross_entropy with related metrics (perplexity, accuracy....)

Comment: Does it makes sense to treat amounts as classes? If the model will predict the amount of, let's say 6, when the real amount is 7, that would be cataloged as a mistake wouldn't it? while that's a good prediction.

Comment: I see now. So a distance loss is indeed accurate here. MAE loss could be expressive here (more interpretable of your model performance than mse). Anyway, a loss per label (mean of loss + std error) could be of a good help here to appreciate what your model is really learning :). So, as a performance check, do prediction on your test set, then group loss by amount.

Comment: So that would help me to see for which labels my prediction is good\bad? What can I conclude from that information?

Comment: Indeed, having prediction error per label will help you to have a precise/detailed view of your model performance. You will be able to compare your loss (the average over labels) with every per-label loss. If your dataset is unbalanced for example, and your model is learning well on the most represented label (which will on average lower your loss), but not on minority labels, you will be able to see it. If all losses per-label are close to your mse/mae, then your mse/mae is representative and low average loss = good learning (you could trust your global loss).